# Как правильно уведомить пользователя об успехе после регистрации?

Tags: php

Пользователь регистрируется, после этого его нужно уведомить, а после, перенаправить на другую страницу. Вопрос, как сделать это правильно? Пробовал так:

```
echo "Регистрация успешно завершена. Переход на страницу аутентификации через 5 секунд...";
sleep(5);
header("Location: ../index.html");
exit;
```

Но `echo` не отображается. Скрипт просто ждёт 5 секунд и открывает `index.html`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все верно. Это не сработает.
Дело в том что вы исполняете php скрипт, а только при завершении происходит отправка echo. 
Также php считает что зачем что-то отправлять когда вы и так захотели перенаправить пользователя! *(тоесть вывод ему не требуется, а требуется исполнять другой скрипт)*

**Вообще это не правильно.** Никто такие вещи не делает. Лучше сделайте редирект на страницу с нужными аргументами типо `header("Location: ../index.html?reok=true");` или специальную страничку. Но ябы не дробил странички, а просто пересмотрел идею скрипта.

Answer (score 0):

То, что вам было нужно, можно записать так

```
header('Refresh:5; url=../index.html');
echo 'Регистрация успешно завершена. Переход на страницу аутентификации через 5 секунд...';
exit;
```

Comment: @Сергей Аксёнов запостил ответ.